# get sequence of group in R

Tags: r, tidyverse

So I have already done what I need but I am sure that there is a better way to do that

```
library(tidyverse)
library(schrute)
office <- schrute::theoffice

top_3_lines_per_episode <- office %>% 
  group_by(season,episode,episode_name,imdb_rating) %>% 
  count(character) %>%
  top_n(3, n) %>% ungroup()

epi_num<-top_3_lines_per_episode %>% 
  select(episode_name) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  mutate(episode_num=row_number()) 

top_3_lines_per_episode %>% 
  inner_join(epi_num)
```

I want to generate column epi_num which gets done using above. A simpler way to do that. I have look at group_indices from SO but I think thats derecated. Need a better way preferably in tidyverse.

Comment: Where did you read about `group_indices` being deprecated?

Comment: I read somewhere on SO, sorry my mistake then though below seems to be perfect. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of `group_indices` being deprecated in fact it seems to be a perfect option here.

```
library(dplyr)

office %>% 
  group_by(season,episode,episode_name,imdb_rating) %>% 
  count(character) %>%
  top_n(3, n) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  mutate(episode_num = group_indices(., season,episode,episode_name,imdb_rating))
```

---

Another option is to combine the columns with `unite` and then `match` to get `episode_num`.

```
office %>% 
  group_by(season,episode,episode_name,imdb_rating) %>% 
  count(character) %>%
  top_n(3, n) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  tidyr::unite(temp, season,episode,episode_name,imdb_rating, remove = FALSE) %>%
  mutate(episode_num = match(temp, unique(temp))) %>%
  select(-temp)
```

Comment: `group_indices()` was deprecated in dplyr 1.0.0. Use instead `mutate(episode_num = cur_group_id())`